# Is it possible to disable message plugin from firing in MS CRM 2011

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

The situation is following:

I've created plugin on `RevokeAccess` message in MS CRM. And in the same time I'm executing `RevokeAccessRequest` from another piece of code. Logically, `RevokeAccess` plugin fires in this case too.

Is there any approach to forbid plugins from firing in certain cases?

Comment: can you explain the logic behind? because the plugin will always fire, but inside you can always check by a condition if the plugin needs to run some code or simply do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to stop it firing by checking the context depth. This shows how nested the call is i.e if it was called from another plugin or straight from CRM

Comment: That's seems to be helpful.